# is any necessary to append "s" after cost in this sentense?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

> It **cost** an arm and a leg.
>
> it **costs** an arm and a leg.

someone tell me there is no need to append "s" after cost.so the first sentence is right.

but i think the second sentence is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences can be correct if you give some context.
The first one has the verb in past simple, the second one has the verb in present simple.

> It cost (me) an arm and a leg.(It **was** very expensive )
>
> It costs am arm and a leg.(It **is** very expensive ).